# Values present in a group on a range of numbers (SQL)

Tags: sql, postgresql, pivot, crosstab

I would like to know how much of a model (let's say t-shirts) with a given range of sizes (let's say 3: X, Y, Z) I have on a given date and on a given store (let's say 3: A, B, C) in stock.

Where:

```
X = between 40 and 50
Y = between 30 and 60
Z = between 20 and 70
```

The final output would look something like this (but with a lot of results):

```
 Date  | Store | Model | Availability X | Availability Y | Availability Z
 02/26 | A     | shirt | Yes            | Yes            | No
 02/26 | B     | shirt | Yes            | No             | No
 02/26 | C     | shirt | Yes            | Yes            | Yes
```

The availablity means I have to have in stock ALL the sizes between the given range of sizes.

I'm still trying to figure out a way to do that. The tables I have are right now designed like this (some illustrative info):

Table "sets"

```
     id | name     | initial_value | final_value
     1  | X        | 40            | 50
     2  | Y        | 30            | 60
     3  | Z        | 20            | 70
```

Table "items"

```
     id | date     | store | model     | size    | in_stock
     1  | 02/26    | A     | shirt     | 40      | 1
     2  | 02/26    | A     | shirt     | 50      | 2
     3  | 02/26    | A     | shirt     | 30      | 0
     4  | 02/26    | B     | shirt     | 30      | 1
```

I appreciate any help! Thanks.

Comment: it is unclear how "ALL" is defined. "ALL sizes between 40 and 50" - does that mean 41,42,43,44,45,46,47....50?

Comment: Yes sir, exactly that.

Comment: this classic example of `crosstab()`

Answer (score 1):

Here is the output for SQL Server, I don't know about postgresql.

-- Create SETS

```
create table dbo.test_sets
(
  id int not null,
  name varchar(255),
  initial_value int not null default (0),
  final_value int not null default(0)
)
go

insert into dbo.test_sets( id, name, initial_value, final_value)
values (1, 'X', 40, 50)

insert into dbo.test_sets( id, name, initial_value, final_value)
values (2, 'Y', 30, 60)

insert into dbo.test_sets( id, name, initial_value, final_value)
values (3, 'Z', 20, 70)
go
```

-- Create ITEMS

```
create table dbo.test_items
(
  id int not null,
  [date] date,
  store varchar(255) not null,
  model varchar(255) not null,
  size int not null default (0),
  in_stock int not null default(0)
)
go

insert into dbo.test_items( id, [date], store, model, size, in_stock)
values (1, '02/26/2016', 'A', 'shirt', 40, 1)

insert into dbo.test_items( id, [date], store, model, size, in_stock)
values (2, '02/26/2016', 'A', 'shirt', 50, 2)

insert into dbo.test_items( id, [date], store, model, size, in_stock)
values (3, '02/26/2016', 'A', 'shirt', 30, 0)

insert into dbo.test_items( id, [date], store, model, size, in_stock)
values (4, '02/26/2016', 'B', 'shirt', 30, 1)

insert into dbo.test_items( id, [date], store, model, size, in_stock)
values (5, '02/26/2016', 'C', 'shirt', 80, 1)
go
```

-- Create NUMBERS LOOKUP

```
create table dbo.test_numbers
(
  id int not null
)
go

declare @first as int
declare @step as int
declare @last as int
select @first = 1, @step = 1, @last = 100

BEGIN TRANSACTION
    WHILE(@first <= @last) 
    BEGIN 
        INSERT INTO dbo.test_numbers VALUES(@first) SET @first += @step 
    END 
COMMIT TRANSACTION
go
```

-- Query to provide required output

```
;with unique_store_models as
(
    select distinct store, model from dbo.test_items
),
set_sizes as
(
    select ts.id, ts.name as size_group, tn.id as size 
    from 
        dbo.test_sets ts 
        inner join dbo.test_numbers tn on 
            tn.id between ts.initial_Value and ts.final_value
),
items_by_sizes_flat as
(
    select 
        ti.[date],
        usm.store,
        usm.model,
        ss.size_group,
        ss.size,
        ti.in_stock
    from 
      unique_store_models usm
      left outer join dbo.test_items ti on 
        ti.store = usm.store 
        and ti.model = usm.model
      left outer join set_sizes ss on 
        ss.size = ti.size
),
items_by_sizes_pivoted as
(
    select
        *
    from
    (
        select
            [date],
            store,
            model,
            size_group,
            --size,
            in_stock
        from 
            items_by_sizes_flat
    ) as p
    PIVOT
    (
        count(in_stock) for size_group in ([X], [Y], [Z])
    ) as pv
)
select 
    [date], 
    store, 
    model, 
    case 
        when [X] > 0 then 'Yes' else 'No' 
    end as [Availability X],
    case 
        when [Y] > 0 then 'Yes' else 'No' 
    end as [Availability Y], 
    case 
        when [Z] > 0 then 'Yes' else 'No' 
    end as [Availability Z] 
from 
    items_by_sizes_pivoted
```

Here is the output for the above input:

[image]

Comment: I think this is the way. I'm going to try out this path. Thank you so much for your time and effort. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try something like this:

```
SELECT      date,
            store,
            model,
            SUM(
                CASE
                    WHEN size BETWEEN (SELECT initial_value FROM Table "sets" WHERE id = 1) AND (SELECT final_value FROM Table "sets" WHERE id = 1) 
                        THEN in_stock
                    ELSE 0
                END
            )       as "Availability X",
            SUM(
                CASE
                    WHEN size BETWEEN (SELECT initial_value FROM Table "sets" WHERE id = 2) AND (SELECT final_value FROM Table "sets" WHERE id = 2) 
                        THEN in_stock
                    ELSE 0
                END
            )       as "Availability Y",
                CASE
                    WHEN size BETWEEN (SELECT initial_value FROM Table "sets" WHERE id = 3) AND (SELECT final_value FROM Table "sets" WHERE id = 3) 
                        THEN in_stock
                    ELSE 0
                END
            )       as "Availability Z"


FROM        Table "items"

WHERE       date > '02/26/2016'
            AND
            date < '02/26/2016'
            AND
            Model = 'shirt'

GROUP BY    date, store, model
```

I think that would give you the information you're after, though if you wanted output exactly as you have it, then you could wrap another case statement around each availability case statement, or use a CTE like below:

```
WITH
data AS
(
SELECT      date,
            store,
            model,
            SUM(
                CASE
                    WHEN size BETWEEN (SELECT initial_value FROM Table "sets" WHERE id = 1) AND (SELECT final_value FROM Table "sets" WHERE id = 1) 
                        THEN in_stock
                    ELSE 0
                END
            )       as availability_x,
            SUM(
                CASE
                    WHEN size BETWEEN (SELECT initial_value FROM Table "sets" WHERE id = 2) AND (SELECT final_value FROM Table "sets" WHERE id = 2) 
                        THEN in_stock
                    ELSE 0
                END
            )       as availability_y,
            SUM(
                CASE
                    WHEN size BETWEEN (SELECT initial_value FROM Table "sets" WHERE id = 3) AND (SELECT final_value FROM Table "sets" WHERE id = 3) 
                        THEN in_stock
                    ELSE 0
                END
            )       as availability_z


FROM        Table "items"

WHERE       date > '02/26/2016'
            AND
            date < '02/26/2016'
            AND
            Model = 'shirt'

GROUP BY    date, store, model
)

SELECT      date, store, model,
            CASE
                WHEN availability_x > 0 THEN "Yes"
                ELSE "No"
            END as "Availability X",
            CASE
                WHEN availability_y > 0 THEN "Yes"
                ELSE "No"
            END as "Availability Y",
            CASE
                WHEN availability_z > 0 THEN "Yes"
                ELSE "No"
            END as "Availability Z"

FROM        data
```

Comment: That's kinda like the way I was doing before, but thanks a lot for your time and effort! Unfortunately this doesn't work out, I need the sets to be all inside the ranges, like 40-50 I need [40,41,42....48,49,50], so "between" wouldn't work.

Comment: I can't edit my post for some reason, but I was going to say that if you need the range to come from a different table, then you can change the between to something like: BETWEEN (SELECT initial_value FROM Table "sets" WHERE id = 1) AND (SELECT final_value FROM Table "sets" WHERE id = 1)  and change the id's for x, y and z.

Answer (score 0):

This classic example of [**`crosstab()`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tablefunc.html) use case.

Sample data:

```
-- DDL and data
CREATE TABLE items(
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  "Date" DATE,
  store TEXT,
  model TEXT,
  size INTEGER,
  in_stock INTEGER
);
INSERT INTO items VALUES
  (1, '02/26/2016':: DATE, 'A', 'shirt', 40, 1),
  (2, '02/26/2016':: DATE, 'A', 'shirt', 50, 2),
  (3, '02/26/2016':: DATE, 'A', 'shirt', 30, 0),
  (4, '02/26/2016':: DATE, 'B', 'shirt', 30, 1);
CREATE TABLE sets(
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  name TEXT,
  initial_value INTEGER,
  final_value INTEGER
);
INSERT INTO sets VALUES
  (1, 'X', 40, 50),
  (2, 'Y', 30, 60),
  (3, 'Z', 20, 70);
```

For selecting I used [**`int4range(start,end,inclusion)`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/rangetypes.html) function to configure size ranges inclusion.Query itself:

```
SELECT * FROM crosstab(
  'SELECT i.store,i."Date",i.model,s.name,
     bool_or(CASE WHEN size_range @> i.size
               THEN TRUE
               ELSE FALSE
             END)
   FROM items i,sets s,int4range(s.initial_value, s.final_value, ''[)'') AS size_range
   WHERE i.in_stock > 0
   GROUP BY 1,2,3,4
   ORDER BY 1,2',
   'SELECT DISTINCT(name) FROM sets ORDER BY 1')
AS output(store TEXT,"Date" DATE,model TEXT,"Availability X" BOOLEAN,"Availability Y" BOOLEAN,"Availability Z" BOOLEAN);
```

Result:

```
 store |    Date    | model | Availability X | Availability Y | Availability Z 
-------+------------+-------+----------------+----------------+----------------
 A     | 2016-02-26 | shirt | t              | t              | t
 B     | 2016-02-26 | shirt | f              | t              | t
(2 rows)
```